# What does `knee atlas` means in an IEEE's paper?

Tags: terminology

I am referring an IEEE's paper for my project which has a term called **knee atlas**, I am not getting the exact meaning of this term, does they mean it a processed image or something else? I am working in `matlab` and here is the paragraph of IEEE's paper:

> > Six atlases were derived from 3-D DESS WE series from six subjectswith visually normal knee images ... The series for three of these atlases were selected from the public release OAI image dataset 0.D.1 and three were from the baseline pilot study. Trained human observers created the knee MRI atlases using manual segmentation.

Comment: Could you link the article or provide a full reference? An excerpt out-of-context is difficult to interpret. For example, we might need to know what OAI means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The knee atlas is an MRI generated with the intent of identifying anatomical features, much like [this](http://xrayhead.com/theatlas.php?id=knee).